# Prove if $T$ is bounded then $T(S_1)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$.

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed space, $T$ is linear operator on $X$ into $Y$, and
$$S_1=\{ x\in X : \| x \| \leq 1 \}.$$
Prove if $T$ is bounded then $T(S_1)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$.

I know the definition of bounded linear operator, i.e.

Let $X \text{ and } Y$ be normed vector spaces (both over $\mathbb R$ or over $\mathbb C$).
A linear transformation or linear operator $T : X \to Y $ is bounded if there is
a constant $C$ such that
$$\Vert Tx \Vert_Y \leq C\Vert x\Vert_X \text{ for all } x \in X.$$

Now, I don't know how to start the proof. I can't associate the definition of bounded linear operator with $T(S_1)$ is a bounded subset of $Y$. Any hint to prove it?

Comment: Since $C<\infty$, and $||x||\leq 1$, $T(S_1)$ is contained in the closed ball $\overline{S_C}$ which is a bounded subset of $Y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in S_1$. Then $\|Tx\|\leq\|T\|\|x\|\leq\|T\|\cdot1=\|T\|$. So $T(S_1)\subset\{y\in Y: \|y\|\leq\|T\|\}$, so $T(S_1)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

$||T(x)||_Y\leq C||x||_X\leq C$ for all $x\in S_1$. That's it.